# Team Foundation Server Compare

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

When doing a compare on a local versus server file, differences are marked with the colors red and blue (text/font color).  What does each color mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the compare window, you should see a small legend that explains the colors:

[image]

Whichever pane it's showing that color in is the version of the file in which that event occurred.

Comment: laughable.  window wasn't exposing the bottom toolbar :) ty

Comment: doh... happens to all of us!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Blue: modified/changed text code;

Red: deleted text code

in versions.

See the key in this image:

[image]

Comment: It's not that bad - I prefer it to Eclipse, even for PHP :o

Comment: Oh no, I have no beef with the IDE.  And I used to write VB.NET years ago..  but I sure don't miss it.  :)

Comment: yeah I have to write in VB sometimes.  it wouldn't be so bad if I didn't know c# already (ability to compare VB to something better :) haha)

Comment: I'm sometimes more happier using Notepad++ to write code. At least, there are no performance issues.

Comment: I rely way too much on intellisense now... so when coding in notepad I have problems with my patience.

Answer (score 1):

- Blue: the line was **modified** in either version of the file.
- Red: the line was **deleted** in either version of the file.